# How do I sort a column in an SSRS report alphabetically AND numerically?

Tags: sql-server, sorting, reportingservices-2005

I know nothing about SSRS

I have an SSRS report with a column containing text and numbers.  I want the column sorted with all the text first sorted alphabetically, then all the numbers sorted numerically.

The data as it stands is all just strings.

Is there a way to do this by simply writing a sort expression, or do I need to do the sort on the data ahead of time somehow and assign a sort order member?

example:

If I have the following:
"cat"
"bear"
"1"
"5.0"
"10"
"-4"
"dog"
"-6"

I would want:

"bear"
"cat"
"dog"
"-6"
"-4"
"1"
"5.0"
"10"

thanks,
Mark Stoddard

Comment: Can you show some sample data and desired results? Are your numbers whole numbers or decimals etc.? You also need to define how to sort things that are "kind of" numbers, such as `.` or `$`.

Comment: Why does 5 get changed to 5.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subject to revision based on the answers to my comment, but here is a start.

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE(bar VARCHAR(32));

INSERT @foo SELECT 'cat'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'bear'
  UNION ALL SELECT '1'
  UNION ALL SELECT '5'
  UNION ALL SELECT '10'
  UNION ALL SELECT '-4'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'dog'
  UNION ALL SELECT '-6';

SELECT bar FROM @foo
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN bar NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.-]%' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN bar NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.-]%' AND bar <> '.' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,3), bar) END,
    bar;
```

Result

```
bar
----------
bear
cat
dog
-6
-4
1
5
10
```

Comment: Nice answer so far, negative numbers?

Comment: Thanks @MStodd I have added the - sign to the pattern match, of course this will increase the likelihood of values that are meant to be text being interpreted as numeric. Also certain values like `.` on its own will cause conversion errors. Hopefully you can state requirements more clearly to help determine if this solution needs to be more robust.

Comment: Will do.  I'll find out tomorrow if it's acceptable to do this in SQL or it needs to be done in SSRS.

Comment: Well, SSRS can always call a stored procedure, right? You can put this SQL code in a stored procedure and not worry what level of support SSRS has for it...